# @Autowired on setter function does not look at the property name (like autowired in XML does)

Tags: spring

I am moving from XML to annotations.

I have the interface types House and My , and class types HouseImpl and MyImpl. Spring injects an MyImpl instance into and MouseImpl instance,

```
public class HouseImpl implements House
    private My my;
    public My getMy2() {
         return my;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setMy2(My my) {
        this.my = my;
    }
```

So the property in `HouseImpl` is called `my2`.

In the Spring configuration file,

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

<bean 
    id="house" 
    class="....HouseImpl"

>
...
</bean>

<bean
    id="my"
    class="my.test.own.spring_book_annotations.MyImpl"

>
</bean> 

<bean
    id="my2"
    class="my.test.own.spring_book_annotations.MyImpl2"

>
</bean>
```

If the configuation is in XML, so there is `autowired="byName"` in the `house` configuration, and no `@Autowired` annotation, then bean `my2` is injected, because the property name is `my2` (`setMy2` is the method). But when we use annotations bean `my` is injected, because the name of the argument of `setMy2` is `my`.

My question is why @Autowired on the setter function does not look at the property name.

Comment: It looks at the setter name; place the annotation on the field to look at the property name.

Comment: With @Autowired on the setter, Spring does not look at the setter name=property node.

Answer (score 0):

When `@Autowired` is used on a setter and there are multiple matching types, the container will look at the parameter name to find the bean to inject. In your case, the parameter is `My my`, so the `my` bean will be injected. You can change the parameter to `My my2`, or use `@Qualifier("my2")` to inject the `my2` bean.

If you want to use the field name, place `@Autowired` on the field itself to use field-injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is like this

```
@Autowired
public void setMy2(My my) {
    this.my = my;
}
```

When you write annotation @Autowired, it will take the bean with setXXX name....here XXX is My2.

Hence your bean with `my2` id is injected.
In order to specify the bean with id as `my` user @Qualifier annotation.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("my")
public void setMy2(My my) {
    this.my = my;
}
```

Comment: No. That's my question. `my` is injected, not `my2`.